# GAE + JPA + Spring - not able to insert data into database (Mysql)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

Hello friends it would be great if some can help me out with this.
I am trying to build a web application on google app engine. I am not able to write data into database using jpa and there is no exception. I tried using flush bt it gives me exception as given below:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:301)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.flush(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.flush(Unknown Source)
  at com.bullbeardevice.dao.impl.BaseDAOImpl.save(BaseDAOImpl.java:52)
  at com.bullbeardevice.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.authenthicateUserLogin(LoginServiceImpl.java:70)
  at com.bullbeardevice.controller.common.LoginController.authenticateUserLogin(LoginController.java:35)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
2014-07-23 17:27:39,731 [1509718305@qtp-1651034737-0] DEBUG (LoginController.java:46) – End of method loginUser of class LoginController
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: This doesn't provide much to go with.  Can you share some more details, like snippets (including any annotations) from `LoginServiceImpl.authenthicateUserLogin` and `BaseDAOImpl.save`, Spring JPA configuration, etc.?

Comment: Hi Manish thanks for your reply My that issue is solved bt I am facing another while fetching records org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'userlogind0_.jdoDetachedState' in 'field list'. I dont have any such field in the query and in my table or entity. I believe this is  used to keep track of the state of the object bt pls tell how i can handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google App Engine [uses the DataNucleus Access Platform](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) as a JPA 1.0 implementation.  By default DataNucleus JPA provider expects every class annotated as `@Entity` to have a `jdoDetachedState` property, mapped to an appropriate column in the database table.

You have the following options:

1. Add a property called `jdoDetachedState` to the entities and add appropriate columns to the tables as well.
2. Switch off detached mode with DataNucleus by following the steps described [in this Google Forums post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/j-f7h7bYeJ8).
3. Add a `transient` property called `jdoDetachedState` to each entity as described [in this DataNucleus JIRA](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCENHANCER-73).

Comment: If I have to go with the first option then what would be be the data type of  jdoDetachedState in DB

Comment: Do you really want to [work with objects in the detached mode](https://db.apache.org/jdo/attach_detach.html)?  If you have a clean architecture where only the business logic loads model objects and works upon them, detachable objects will not be required with DataNucleus and you should use option #2 listed above.  If you do decide to go with option #1, the Java data type will be `Object[]` and the database type should he `BLOB`.  But again, this property is only used at runtime by DataNucleus and is never persisted so you should try and avoid using option #1.

Comment: Thanks Manish For you quick response. I have already used option 2 bt the problem with that solution is it works randomly. sometimes it works sometimes it gives the same error.

Comment: And one more this I would like to ask you as I am new to app engine is this problem due to the multiple @onetomany mapping that I have in my entity..?

Comment: Switching off detached mode should work all the time.  Just check that you have annotated all the entities correctly.  It will also be useful to try a sample project on GAE first, with just a single entity.  Make that work without errors a few times. Then add another entity and make this work as well.  Repeat once more so that everything is proven to work correctly.  Remember that GAE offers a restricted JEE environment so everything may not work correctly in the first attempt and you may have to find workarounds.  As for your other problem, post it as a new question for someone to check.

Answer (score 0):

My entity class looks like this :

```
package com.bullbeardevice.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user_registration database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_registration")
@NamedQuery(name = "UserRegistration.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRegistration u")
public class UserRegistration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_Registration_Id")
    private String userRegistrationId;

    @Column(name = "account_Status")
    private int accountStatus;

    @Column(name = "created_By")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "created_On")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "email_Address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "expiry_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date expiryDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Group_Master_Id")
    private GroupMaster groupMaster;

    @Column(name = "modified_By")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modified_On")
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "permissions")
    private int permissions;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Chat
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<Chat> chats;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Coupon
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<Coupon> coupons;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to DeviceDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<DeviceDetail> deviceDetails;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Portfolio
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<Portfolio> portfolios;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to UserDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<UserDetail> userDetails;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to UserLoginDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<UserLoginDetail> userLoginDetails;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to UserRoleMaster
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_Role_Master_Id")
    private UserRoleMaster userRoleMaster;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Watch
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRegistration")
    private List<Watch> watches;

    public UserRegistration() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the userRegistrationId
     */
    public String getUserRegistrationId() {
        return userRegistrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userRegistrationId
     *            the userRegistrationId to set
     */
    public void setUserRegistrationId(String userRegistrationId) {
        this.userRegistrationId = userRegistrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the accountStatus
     */
    public int getAccountStatus() {
        return accountStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @param accountStatus
     *            the accountStatus to set
     */
    public void setAccountStatus(int accountStatus) {
        this.accountStatus = accountStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @return the createdBy
     */
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * @param createdBy
     *            the createdBy to set
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * @return the createdOn
     */
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * @param createdOn
     *            the createdOn to set
     */
    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the emailAddress
     */
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param emailAddress
     *            the emailAddress to set
     */
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return the expiryDate
     */
    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param expiryDate
     *            the expiryDate to set
     */
    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the groupMaster
     */
    public GroupMaster getGroupMaster() {
        return groupMaster;
    }

    /**
     * @param groupMaster
     *            the groupMaster to set
     */
    public void setGroupMaster(GroupMaster groupMaster) {
        this.groupMaster = groupMaster;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modifiedBy
     */
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * @param modifiedBy
     *            the modifiedBy to set
     */
    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modifiedOn
     */
    public Date getModifiedOn() {
        return modifiedOn;
    }

    /**
     * @param modifiedOn
     *            the modifiedOn to set
     */
    public void setModifiedOn(Date modifiedOn) {
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password
     *            the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the permissions
     */
    public int getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    /**
     * @param permissions
     *            the permissions to set
     */
    public void setPermissions(int permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    /**
     * @return the chats
     */
    public List<Chat> getChats() {
        return chats;
    }

    /**
     * @param chats
     *            the chats to set
     */
    public void setChats(List<Chat> chats) {
        this.chats = chats;
    }

    public Chat addChat(Chat chat) {
        getChats().add(chat);
        chat.setUserRegistration(this);

        return chat;
    }

    public Chat removeChat(Chat chat) {
        getChats().remove(chat);
        chat.setUserRegistration(null);

        return chat;
    }

    public List<Coupon> getCoupons() {
        return this.coupons;
    }

    public void setCoupons(List<Coupon> coupons) {
        this.coupons = coupons;
    }

    public Coupon addCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        getCoupons().add(coupon);
        coupon.setUserRegistration(this);

        return coupon;
    }

    public Coupon removeCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        getCoupons().remove(coupon);
        coupon.setUserRegistration(null);

        return coupon;
    }

    public List<DeviceDetail> getDeviceDetails() {
        return this.deviceDetails;
    }

    public void setDeviceDetails(List<DeviceDetail> deviceDetails) {
        this.deviceDetails = deviceDetails;
    }

    public DeviceDetail addDeviceDetail(DeviceDetail deviceDetail) {
        getDeviceDetails().add(deviceDetail);
        deviceDetail.setUserRegistration(this);

        return deviceDetail;
    }

    public DeviceDetail removeDeviceDetail(DeviceDetail deviceDetail) {
        getDeviceDetails().remove(deviceDetail);
        deviceDetail.setUserRegistration(null);

        return deviceDetail;
    }

    public List<Portfolio> getPortfolios() {
        return this.portfolios;
    }

    public void setPortfolios(List<Portfolio> portfolios) {
        this.portfolios = portfolios;
    }

    public Portfolio addPortfolio(Portfolio portfolio) {
        getPortfolios().add(portfolio);
        portfolio.setUserRegistration(this);

        return portfolio;
    }

    public Portfolio removePortfolio(Portfolio portfolio) {
        getPortfolios().remove(portfolio);
        portfolio.setUserRegistration(null);

        return portfolio;
    }

    public List<UserDetail> getUserDetails() {
        return this.userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(List<UserDetail> userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

    public UserDetail addUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        getUserDetails().add(userDetail);
        userDetail.setUserRegistration(this);

        return userDetail;
    }

    public UserDetail removeUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        getUserDetails().remove(userDetail);
        userDetail.setUserRegistration(null);

        return userDetail;
    }

    public List<UserLoginDetail> getUserLoginDetails() {
        return this.userLoginDetails;
    }

    public void setUserLoginDetails(List<UserLoginDetail> userLoginDetails) {
        this.userLoginDetails = userLoginDetails;
    }

    public UserLoginDetail addUserLoginDetail(UserLoginDetail userLoginDetail) {
        getUserLoginDetails().add(userLoginDetail);
        userLoginDetail.setUserRegistration(this);

        return userLoginDetail;
    }

    public UserLoginDetail removeUserLoginDetail(UserLoginDetail userLoginDetail) {
        getUserLoginDetails().remove(userLoginDetail);
        userLoginDetail.setUserRegistration(null);

        return userLoginDetail;
    }

    public UserRoleMaster getUserRoleMaster() {
        return this.userRoleMaster;
    }

    public void setUserRoleMaster(UserRoleMaster userRoleMaster) {
        this.userRoleMaster = userRoleMaster;
    }

    public List<Watch> getWatches() {
        return this.watches;
    }

    public void setWatches(List<Watch> watches) {
        this.watches = watches;
    }

    public Watch addWatch(Watch watch) {
        getWatches().add(watch);
        watch.setUserRegistration(this);

        return watch;
    }

    public Watch removeWatch(Watch watch) {
        getWatches().remove(watch);
        watch.setUserRegistration(null);

        return watch;
    }

}
```